# Managing multiple SSH keys with TeamCity

Tags: git, github, teamcity, ssh-keys

We have a GitHub Enterprise server which is working against an instance of TeamCity which has build agents on a number of servers.

To authenticate we are currently adding the ssh keys manually and referencing them but this is not a scalable solution since we need to add the keys to all of the build agent boxes.

Can anyone think of a better way to manage this?

note: we cannot create a "build" user in github and then add that to each of our projects.

Answer (score 0):

If I consider the [GitHub Enterprise FAQ](https://enterprise.github.com/faq#faq-4), I see:

> Can I use my organization's LDAP directory to manage user access?
>
> Yes. GitHub Enterprise supports user authentication via external LDAP or CAS services. The setup process includes a step for configuring your organization's LDAP/CAS server information.
>
> By default, GitHub Enterprise runs in a self-contained authentication mode with user information stored in the GitHub Enterprise database.

If you cannot "create a "build" user in github and then add that to each of our projects", that means you cannot (or don't want) reuse the same public/private ssh key on each build server.

That would leave you with https access instead of ssh addresses, using LDAP-based credentials.
No ssh key to publish/register on the GitHub enterprise server, so it is a possible "solution/workaround".
But that would leave you with another set of problem:

- which (actual LDAP) account will you use on each of those servers?
- How will you manage the password renewal which is often mandatory every x month for said LDAP accounts?

Comment: We are authenticating users using Active Directory (via LDAP). Our infra team won't allow us to add a "build" user to our domain thus that requirement...

Comment: @JamesHollingworth that means GitHub Enterprise only support ssh user management, much like GitLab... (until recently: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/1016)

Answer (score 0):

Put the .ssh folders on a share?